# SATA hard disk for laptop on Desktop PC

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata, desktop-computer

Can I connect a laptop SATA hard disk to Desktop PC? Do I have to use some adapters or I can just plug in SATA power connector and SATA data cable like my Desktop hard disk is connected?

I noticed that both laptop and desktop SATA disks use same connectors, but I'm afraid that I might fry my laptop hard disk because the SATA connector has both 12V and 5V voltage (given the fact that laptop hard disks has input voltage of 5V)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can interchange them as they use the same voltage and same interface. The extra +12V pins are unused on laptops. You will need a mounting bracket.